# "profile" is not a valid parameter - Elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, kibana

This is in relation with my yet to be answered question: [Count the number of occurrence of my keywords from all the retrieved documents - Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707099/count-the-number-of-occurrence-of-my-keywords-from-all-the-retrieved-documents)

So I found a possible lead which is to use the **profile** API / parameter to display the `term frequency` of my keyword from a list of my retrieved documents

[image: Profile]

Now the I'm trying to use it with the following dependencies for my application:

Elasticsearch: v7.1 
PHP: v7.2 
Laravel: v5.7 
Elasticsearch/elasticsearch PHP API: v7.1

Whenever I'm adding the `profile => true` parameter, it is displaying the following error

[image: php]

But when I use it in the **Kibana**, it's working perfectly fine

[image: Kibana Profile]

[image: Kibana Result]

Does this mean the **profile** parameter is not yet implemented in the Elasticsearch/elasticsearch API? Or is there a trick or workaround for this?

Comment: Shouldn't `profile => true` be inside `body` array in parallel to the `query`

Comment: hello sir @NishantSaini, as for the Elasticsearch/elasticsearch API, the "query" is inside the body, as for the raw ES query, the query is a standalone param whenever typed in the Kibana

tried putting it as a sibling of "query", it still says "not recognized"

Comment: oh my bad! it worked! I made the `profile => true` params as a sibling of the `query` params THIS IS THE ANSWER! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

may you post an answer here? so I can upvote your suggestion sir @NishantSaini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `profile => true` as an element of `body` array as below:

```
$params = [
   ...
   ...
   'body' => [
      'profile' => true,
      'query' => [
         ...
         ...
      ]
   ]
]
```